# gizmo ignores when i try to use it

Tags: transforms, gizmo

When I try to use the gizmo to rotate, move, scale or anything, it will just think I'm trying to select a bunch of bones instead. The hotkeys like <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> still work but this has no reason to not be working anymore. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what I'm seeing there - why is there this dashed line box at the gizmo inside the red circle?

Comment: thats me trying to rotate it but blender is drag selecting instead